# Workspace switcher bindings do not always work?

Tags: 11.04, unity, workspaces

Is it normal that switching through workspaces with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +<kbd>alt</kbd> +<kbd>left/right/up/down</kbd> doesn't work when I close the last window on the active desktop?

Is there a way to alter this behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you set nautilus to **not** draw the desktop? To find that out, run this command:

```
gconftool-2 --get /apps/nautilus/preferences/show_desktop
```

If it returns true, then its a bug. I know you've filed [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/800278) and I'm the guy who commented there.

If it returns false, then its a known issue in Unity, to not un-focus closed windows when Nautilus is not running (currently it depends on Nautilus to take away focus from the closed application).

Comment: It does return `true`. I already wrote that in launchpad. Srsly ... I hate unity.

Comment: Are there maybe some settings that I could try out? I mean ... I use all 4 workspaces all the time - mostly using my mouse only for clicking the desktop so I can use the workspace switcher keys ... -.-

Answer (score 0):

It is highly likely that something is messing up the focus tracking.
You could try to try to change the focus tracking behaviour in `ccsm` and see if that solves it. (You could try using low).

[image]

Comment: Doesn't change anything - though it seems like it's in some way the cause of my issue ... f.e. after closing the pidgin contact list, it somehow is still focussed, so I need to click at the desktop in order to be able to use the unity hotkeys again ~.~

Comment: @tesseract you could probably report a bug. I get similar problems, but normally changing the focus behaviour works for me.

Comment: Bug reported at:[link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/800278)